# How to use ComboChart with GWT visualization

Tags: gwt, gwt-visualization

Anyone knows if its posible to use the Google ComboChart with GWT . I tried using the wrapper in [GWT Visualization Wrapper](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/downloads/detail?name=gwt-visualization-1.1.2.zip&can=2&q=) but I get the error sun.misc.InvalidJarIndexException: Invalid index

Im using the jar found in [GWT official jar](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can combine google Combochart with GWT easily. with the same jar that you mentioned. follow [this link.](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted?tm=6).

The error that you are facing is sounds like jar version issue.

Comment: Thanks , the problem was that I renamed the new jar with another name. The solution was to replace the jar with the same name https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gwt-ext/YUwdZKzHneM